# Create Table using inner join in sql

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-workbench

I am supposed to create a table in sql using inner join and another tables. I came with such a solution but MySQL Workbench keeps telling me that there is an error in my SQL syntax. I am out of any ideas. I'd be grateful if someone will help me.

```
 CREATE TABLE BigTable AS( 
 SELECT
    ProductName, SupplierID, CategoryID, QuantityPerUnit, UnitPrice, UnitsInStock, UnitsOnOrder, ReorderLevel, Discontinued
 FROM `northwind`.`products`
 INNER JOIN(
     SELECT 
        CustomerID, EmployeeID, OrderDate, RequiredDate, ShipVia, Freight, ShipName, ShipAddress, ShipCity, ShipRegion, ShipPostalCode, ShipCountry, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount 
     FROM `northwind`.`orders` 
     INNER JOIN `northwind`.`order_details`
     ON orders.OrderID=order_details.OrderID) AS products
 INNER JOIN(
     SELECT
        LastName, FirstName ,Title ,TitleOfCourtesy ,BirthDate ,HireDate ,Address ,City , Region, PostalCode, Country, HomePhone, Extension, Photo, Notes, ReportsTo, CompanyName,ContactName,ContactTitle,Address,City,Region,PostalCode,Country,Phone,Fax,
     FROM `northwind`.`employees`
     INNER JOIN `northwind`.`customers`) AS People));
```

Comment: Don't put parentheses after `AS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the outer set of parentheses. It should be:

```
CREATE TABLE BigTable AS
SELECT
    ProductName, SupplierID, CategoryID, QuantityPerUnit, UnitPrice, UnitsInStock, UnitsOnOrder, ReorderLevel, Discontinued
FROM `northwind`.`products`
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT 
        CustomerID, EmployeeID, OrderDate, RequiredDate, ShipVia, Freight, ShipName, ShipAddress, ShipCity, ShipRegion, ShipPostalCode, ShipCountry, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount 
    FROM `northwind`.`orders` 
    INNER JOIN `northwind`.`order_details`
    ON orders.OrderID=order_details.OrderID) AS products
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT
        LastName, FirstName ,Title ,TitleOfCourtesy ,BirthDate ,HireDate ,Address ,City , Region, PostalCode, Country, HomePhone, Extension, Photo, Notes, ReportsTo, CompanyName,ContactName,ContactTitle,Address,City,Region,PostalCode,Country,Phone,Fax
    FROM `northwind`.`employees`
    INNER JOIN `northwind`.`customers`) AS People;
```

You also had mismatched parentheses, since you had two `))` at the end matching the opening `(`, and an extra `,` after `Fax`.

These will fix the syntax errors. But it also looks like you have logic errors, as most of your `INNER JOIN` clauses are missing `ON` conditions to relate the tables. And you're selecting lots of columns that you never use.

Comment: thank You very much. I was trying to do tho that way, since CREATE TABLE BigTable AS( 
SELECT CustomerID, EmployeeID, OrderDate, RequiredDate, ShipVia, Freight, ShipName, ShipAddress, ShipCity, ShipRegion, ShipPostalCode, ShipCountry, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount 
FROM `northwind`.`orders` 
INNER JOIN `northwind`.`order_details` 
ON orders.OrderID=order_details.OrderID ); has worked :) I'll try to follow Your hints